# Replace of NOT REGEXP_LIKE from Oracle to Postgres

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Please help me how to Migrate to Postgres  the below Code which uses NOT REGEXP_LIKE In Oracle:

```
  UPDATE TBL_RESOURCEAVAILUPLOAD
    SET IS_VALID_AVAILABILITY = 0,
      ERROR_CODE = 'DATA-ERR',
      ERROR_MESSAGE = CONCAT(ERROR_MESSAGE,' Start date or end date is not in proper format. It should be in MM/DD/YYYY format.,')
        WHERE ( **NOT REGEXP_LIKE** (STARTDATE, '(0[0-9]|1[0-2])/(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])/([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])')
                        OR
                        **NOT REGEXP_LIKE** (ENDDATE, '(0[0-9]|1[0-2])/(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])/([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])') )
                     AND BATCH_ID = 21354
                      AND COUNTRY_ID = '76';
```

Comment: Why are you storing DATE values in a VARCHAR columns? Don't do that. If those columns were proper DATE (or TIMESTAMP) columns you wouldn't even need that check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
 UPDATE TBL_RESOURCEAVAILUPLOAD 
    SET IS_VALID_AVAILABILITY = 0,
    ERROR_CODE = 'DATA-ERR', 
    ERROR_MESSAGE = CONCAT(ERROR_MESSAGE,' Start date or end date is not in proper format. It should be in MM/DD/YYYY format.,') 
  WHERE ( 
        STARTDATE !~ '(0[0-9]|1[0-2])/(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])/([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])' 
        OR ENDDATE !~ '(0[0-9]|1[0-2])/(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])/([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])'
        )
    AND BATCH_ID = 21354 
    AND COUNTRY_ID = '76';
```